# sinatra -- unknown media type

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra

I am writing a blog for games, loading files with extension `*.sgf` Sinatra doesn't recognize this.

> Unknown media type: ".sgf"  file: base.rb location: content_type line: 132

The backtrace mentions `webrick`

> /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb in service
>         si.service(req, res) /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb in run
>             server.service(req, res) /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb in block in start_thread
>             block ? block.call(sock) : run(sock)

I caught this since although my Sinatra app works when I do `ruby myApp.rb` it doesn't work when I do `foreman start` for Heroku (and it didn't work when I deployed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should configure `Sinatra` to understand your MIME-type:

```
configure do
  mime_type :sgf, 'application/octet-stream'
end
```

or inplace:

```
get '/upload' do
  content_type :sgf
  # Do what you want with the file
end
```

[More info](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Mime%20Types).